# javascript_include_tag output safe html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I've updated http://tetalab.org/ with RefineryCMS 1.0.8, and now, our stylesheets and javascripts are outputted as safe html, breaking anything on the site.

Exemple of code outputting safe html:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'modernizr-min' %>
```

Code found in html source:

```
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/modernizr-min.js&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

Could someone provide some tips about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you're using refinerycms-theming plugin.

This plugin does bad things and is [not recommended](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-theming#readme)

I think if you removed that the problem would go away :)